# Insufficient permissions to write Apache logs to APACHE_LOG_DIR in Ubuntu Server for azureuser

Tags: apache, ubuntu, azure

I write to /home/azureuser/ directory (I have rigths) but I want write to APACHE_LOG_DIR (I no have rigths). 
How to resolve this problem? See below my forum.conf.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/forum
        ServerName forum.example.com
        # ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/forum/error.log
        # CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/forum/access.log combined
        ErrorLog /home/azureuser/error_log
        CustomLog /home/azureuser/access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

command below resolve this problem

```
sudo chmod 0777 /var/log/apache2/forum
```